# Finding nearest timestamp in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, nearest-neighbor

in Mathematica I have to find a timestamp closest to a given one. I have:

```
alltrafotstamps = (DateList[#1]) & @@@ reddata[[All, 1]]
```

what gives something what looks like a list of timestamps:

```
{"2017-11-10 21:36:12.135", "2017-11-10 21:36:50.535",
 "2017-11-10 21:37:28.935", "2017-11-10 21:38:07.335", ...}
```

So now I do:

```
Nearest[alltrafotstamps, DateList["2017-11-10 22:56:50.535"]]
```

and I get this message:

```
Nearest::neard: The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair 2017 and 2017-11-10 21:36:12.135.
```

Can it be that Nearest cannot do this for timestamp, but can do it only for times?

Answer (score 0):

```
alltrafotstamps = {
  "2017-11-10 21:36:12.135",
  "2017-11-10 21:36:50.535",
  "2017-11-10 21:37:28.935",
  "2017-11-10 21:38:07.335"};

target = "2017-11-10 21:37:00";

nearest = Nearest[
   AbsoluteTime /@ alltrafotstamps,
   AbsoluteTime[target]];

DateObject @@ nearest

DateList @@ nearest
```

> ```
> {2017, 11, 10, 21, 36, 50.535}
> ```

Comment: It works, thanks! It is a pity that Nearest does not work directly on Date objects.